# How make a textarea with changeable width and height and with a lable on the upper border on the right corner with HTML5 and CSS3

Tags: html, css

I neeed to make a textarea with changeable width and height and with a lable on the upper border on the right corner with HTML5 and CSS3 like below picture :
[image]

How can I do this? Any help will be appriciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
body { font-size:14px; }
.form-control { display:inline-block; position:relative;}
label { text-align:right; background-color:white; right:5px; top:-5px; position:absolute;}
textarea { display:block; }
```

```html
<div class="form-control">
<label for="#myTextArea">My Label</label>
<textarea>My text area</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is not like what I want. The lable is not on the border! I need something like fieldset

Comment: Updated with the changes requested